# How to see actual data sent by httpClient.execute(...);?

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I send get/post data to external web site using apache httpclient: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomContext.java

Not all things work fine with POST request and I would like to make sure I form header properly. Is there any way for me to see EXACT information sent by httpClient.execute(...);?

Thank you!

Comment: You can turn the log level way up then it will dump the whole network traffic into your logging system.

Comment: If you are using `Eclipse` then it's `TCP\IP Monitor` would be the right tool for you.

Comment: 2Thilo: how to enable logs? Are you talking about some apache library settings? Does it have configuration (API to call?) to set the logging level? or...? And I use IntelliJ IDEA, not eclipse, though it looks like I just need to have any type of network sniffer...